Passing a reference type object with or without ref when there is no reassignment
If there is reassignment, passing a reference type with ref changes the behaviour, e.g.:
static void ReassignArray(int[] arr)
{
    arr = new int[] { 99, 98, 97 }; // This reassignment does not affect the original array 
}

static void ReassignArrayWithRef(ref int[] arr)
{
    arr = new int[] { 99, 98, 97 }; // This reassignment affects the original array
}

However, is there a difference when changing the object directly:
static void ChangeFirst(int[] arr) {
    arr[0] = 4;  // will affect the original array
}

static void ChangeFirst(ref int[] arr) {
    arr[0] = 6;  // will affect the original array
}

My question is therefore, apart from potential performance gains for the method with the ref keyword (no need to create a new pointer), is there a difference between passing a reference type object with ref and passing a reference type object without ref, in situations where there is no reassignment?
My question is not a duplicate of Does it make sense to pass a "reference type" to a method as a parameter with 'ref' key?. I'm asking specifically in the instances when there is no reassignment.

"apart from obvious performance gains for the method with the ref" Presumably you meant the obvious performance costs.  It's just strictly worse.

What performance costs? For arrays, passing without the ref keyword also passes a (copy of the) reference to the array object. But whether you have a copy or the original reference, it's still writing a reference entry to the stack frame to make the function call.

@JoelCoehoorn The performance cost of generation a reference to the variable, of dereferencing the value twice instead of once (technically only paid if you ever actually use the variable, but paid each time you use the variable), and in the case where the parameter's value wasn't stored in a mutable variable in the first place, the cost (in both memory and time) of constructing a variable in which to store it.

I agree that this is not a duplicate and worth reopening. To answer the question: without reassignment there is no functional difference and there is no reason to use ref.

@freakish Odd, considering you're just quoting the answer from the duplicate.

@Servy odd, considering you think I'm quoting any of those answers.

“It makes sense if you think you might make the variable point to a different object (or to null) inside your method.
Otherwise, no.” in the duplicate does seem to answer the question.

@freakish There absolutely could be a functional difference if you use ref then you can get the target location to point to an entirely different array. The duplicate points this out exactly. Ergo, if you are not doing this then there is no difference. So the duplicate answers it either way. Putting it another way: if you think there is a difference without doing reassignment then you should post an answer over there pointing that out, because that question does not specify what it's doing.

"apart from obvious performance costs for the method with the ref keyword" -- I don't think that there is anything obvious regarding the performance characteristics of the two approaches. I am pretty sure that if we make a survey among developers of all levers of seniority, at least 50% will be reluctant to even make a guess about which is faster. I would suggest to remove this assumption from the question. In case you don't care about the performance, just say that you don't care about it, and say instead about what aspect you care about. This would be an improvement for the question IMHO.

I thought that adding the ref keyword was avoiding creation of a new pointer which would result in a performance gain but after benchmarking it it doesn't seem obvious at all. I'll take it out, you are right.


apart from potential performance gains for the method with the ref keyword (no need to create a new pointer), is there a difference between passing a reference type object with ref and passing a reference type object without ref, in situations where there is no reassignment?

First off, a new pointer is not created. The performance difference in the above example is negligible: one CIL instruction.
For the following example:
public static void Main() {
    int[] arr = {5,6,7};
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{arr[0]}");
    ChangeA(arr);
    Console.WriteLine($"{arr[0]}");
    ChangeB(ref arr);
    Console.WriteLine($"{arr[0]}");
}

public static void ChangeA(int[] arr) {
    arr[0] = 4;  // will affect the original array
}

public static void ChangeB(ref int[] arr) {
    arr[0] = 6;  // will affect the original array
}

You can investigate the generated IL with something like ILSpy or sharplab.io online.
.method public hidebysig static 
    void ChangeA (
        int32[] arr
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20e2
    // Code size 6 (0x6)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.4
    IL_0004: stelem.i4
    IL_0005: ret
} // end of method C::ChangeA

and
.method public hidebysig static 
    void ChangeB (
        int32[]& arr
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20e9
    // Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldind.ref
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0004: ldc.i4.6
    IL_0005: stelem.i4
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method C::ChangeB

ldind.ref transforms an address on the stack.
stelem.i4 consumes the previous three values on the stack to store the value into an array index.

I hope this is not a naive question but to my understanding "Passing a reference-type argument by value copies the reference (but not the object)"*, which I don't see in the IL you showed. Presumably, the copying happen before "ldarg.0" which loads the first argument passed to the method onto the evaluation stack, right? *quote from C# 12 in a Nutshell The Definitive Reference
